# List of friends/family members to store as lead in infusionsoft - WordPress site integration

Tags: php, wordpress, email, contact-form-7, infusionsoft

**Initial Requirements:**

Client/Referrer’s First Name, Last Name, Email Address
List of their friends/family members First Name, Last Name, and Email address
Personalized message.

Then those names would be added to our infusionsoft system as leads, with proper referral field set.

Then we would send out an automated email which would take the clients personal message and put it before some predesign content which would then be sent out to the emails that were entered in the list.

The email would come from the client/referrer’s email address (not from our website).

**What I have done so far:**

I am using Contact Form 7- InfusionSoft Add-on (https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-infusionsoft-add-on)

InfusionSoft integration is done, form is sending data from website and storing them in InfusionSoft as lead.

**How I can:**
- Store Friends data as lead too in InfusionSoft and the referral info associated with them.

**What I am trying:**
I am trying to utilize Tags for this purpose, but not getting it.

**Any suggestions will be appreciated** Thanks!